# android edittext and textview scroll together

Tags: android, scroll

I have a edittext and textview next to each other. I'd like, when I scroll with the edittext(either with finger or by adding new content to edittext) that the textview scroll the same distance. I've tried querying the getScrollY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question perfectly, but if I do, then I would suggest putting these two elements side by side in a Horizontal linear layout within a Scroll View. This way if / when either of the elements are moved, they will stay with each other.